# Custom ViewModel is not found

Tags: php, magento2

Whenever I try to use my own custom ViewModel the module stops working. Error: `main.CRITICAL: Class Lith\Contacts\ViewModel\AdditionalInfo does not exist [] []`

The file structure is simple:

```
- code
  - Lith
    - Contacts
      - etc
      - view
        - frontend
          - layout
          - templates
          - web
      - ViewModel
```

Inside the `view\frontend\layout` I created a file `contact_index_index.xml` Where I defined a new `block` inside a `referenceContainer` with a static message - Works fine. But when I add an argument, to pass in a ViewModel, it stops working (the static message doesn't appear) with my custom ViewModel. NOTE works fine if I pass existing Magento ViewModel.

The argument:

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Lith\Contacts\ViewModel\AdditionalInfo</argument>
</arguments>
```

The ViewModel class is created inside `ViewModel` folder and called `AdditionalInfo.php`. Its code:

```
<?php

namespace Lith\Contacts\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class AdditionalInfo implements ArgumentInterface
{
    public function getMessage(): string
    {
        return 'Addition info text test - from a ViewModel';
    }
}
```

The template itself doesn't use the ViewModel - its just a static `div` with a string text hence it's not important.

This all when loading the website doesn't work. It does not find a ViewModel.

But whenever I change the `argument` from the one above to this:

```
<arguments>
    <argument
name="view_model"
xsi:type="object"
>Magento\Contact\ViewModel\UserDataProvider</argument>
</arguments>
```

Then it works fine.

If i remove the `<argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Lith\Contacts\ViewModel\AdditionalInfo</argument>`, since ViewModel in the template is not used right now, it also works fine as it renders the text.

Why it doesn't find my custom ViewModel? What did I do wrong?

EDIT: Heres a public repository of the files if any additional info is required https://bitbucket.org/Edvbar/magento2/src/master/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lith_Contacts module on Bitbucket is added to the folder `app/design/code/Lith/Contacts`. But this should not be put in the design folder.

Please move the module to `app/code/Lith/Contacts`. Afterwards run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from command line to enable module.